# call a same instance component multiple times ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have next modal component in React:

```
class Modal extends Component {
 render(){
   return(     
    <div className="modal-content">
      <div className="modal-header">
        { this.props.modalHeader }
      </div>
      <div className="modal-body" className={this.props.className}>
        { this.props.modalBody }
      </div>
      <div className="modal-footer">
        { this.props.modalFooter }
      </div>
    </div>);
  }
}
```

And I'm using it this way:

```
 render(){

  return(
        <Modal 
           modalHeader={<ContentComponent getSection='header'/>}
           modalBody={<ContentComponent getSection='body'/>}
           modalFooter={<ContentComponent getSection='footer'/>}
        />
  );
 }
```

There is any way to get a reference of ContentComponent and pass this same reference into the 3 props?

I have tried reference in a constant but doesn't work.

Comment: I need some clarification of what you mean by "reference of ContentComponent"? Are you referring to createRef(), or do you just mean a shared instance?
Also, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Shammoo I mean to a share instance, I want to create some functions on the ContentComponent and share information between 3 sections elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function that returns a ContentComponent

```
const ccWrapper = (section)=>(<ContentComponent getSection={section}/>)
//later in code
modalHeader={ccWrapper('header')}
```

If ContentComponent is a function it's even easier:

```
modalHeader={ContentComponent({getSection:'header'})}
```

You could also let getSection be set by Modal:

```
<Modal cc={ContentComponent} />
//in modal
const {cc:ContentComponent} = props;
//...
<div className="modal-header">
  <ContentComponent getSection="header" />
```

Comment: Last one I'm getting error: `React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined`

Comment: @JoseRojas are you sure you're passing `ContentComponent` as a prop called `cc` to Modal? In Modal ContentComponent is undefined so either you didn't pass it correctly or you didn't destructure it correctly.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I'm passing ContentComponent as cc to Modal, when I look at cc is a function

Comment: @JoseRojas did you log out what ContentComponent is in Modal?

Comment: If I log ContentComponent into modal is undefined, but if I log cc is a function.

Comment: @JoseRojas Then you passed the prop correctly but didn't destructure it correct, maybe try `const ContentComponent = props.cc` instead of `const {cc:ContentComponent} = props;`